# Do I need to call de destructor here?

Tags: c++

Ok, so lets say I have a heap allocated object... if I use placement new and create a new object in the memory location where the other used to 'live', will that cause a memory leak? Or, and this is what I think, will it overwrite it?

```
Object* ptr = new Object(1);
new(ptr) Object(2);
```

Or would I need to call the destructor explicitly cos it doesn't get overwritten?

```
Object* ptr = new Object(1);
delete ptr;
new(ptr) Object(2);
```

Comment: why are you using placement new in the first place?

Comment: Not a memory leak, but undefined behavior that will [make demons fly out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: i'm doing some weird things with arrays and it's just a question that i came up with, and i can't find it anywhere

Comment: `delete` does more that just calling the destructor.

Comment: Not all questions that do things that don't specfically make sense in their scenarios are necessarily bad. They can be purely out of curiousity too. SO needs to stop with answering "why would you do that?" to all of these.

Comment: @HattedRooster my comment was targeted at trying to understand what are OPs expectations, not to say "don't ask this question". Though, I can see what you mean. Will try to keep it in mind

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Yeah I didn't mean you specifically, I understand your motive, I've just seen this trend growing overall and it worries me that questions can't be asked anymore for curious minds under the narrative "what if?"

Comment: what if the first object has been `std::move`d? cos moving leaves that first object in kind of and 'empty state' doesn't it? so all the pointers that object could have are now set to nullptr right??

Comment: @Karlos, Only if the type's move constructor or move assignment operator nulls them out itself. Moving primitive types is the same as copying them. However, you still need to destroy moved-from objects in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Both options are wrong.

Calling new operator causes 2 things: allocating a memory and calling constructor. Placement new only calls a constructor on the preallocated piece of memory. Calling delete, on the other hand, causes both calling destructor and freeing the memory. What you have to do after placement new is to call a destructor explicitelly. But in C++ the best option is always using RAII pattern.

Answer (score 1):

With placement new, you need to call explicitly the destructor, which is different than calling `delete`.

Something like:

```
typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(Object), alignof(Object)>::type buffer;

Object* ptr = new (&buffer) Object(1);
// ...
ptr->~Object(); // Destructor call.
```